# Why am I getting "invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?"?

Tags: python

This happens almost every time I type `print("something here")`: it puts this error message box (and yes I've tried quotation marks instead of quote marks).

[image: error message box]

Comment: Did you enter the code in the image? It has in fact a syntax error.

Comment: `print('hello' +inp 'how is your day?')` You don't have anything between `inp` and `'how is your day?'`  You need a comma or a plus sign.

Comment: voting to close as this is a typo

Answer (score 2):

Currently you have

```
print('hello' +inp 'how is your day?')
```

You might want to place another + sign on the other end of your input variable.

```
print('hello' +inp+ 'how is your day?')
```

Comment: If this is the source of the problem, I would suggest using an f-string instead.  `print(f"hello {inp} how is your day?")`. Given the lack of spaces, it seems more likely the OP meant to use commas and rely on `print` using a space as its default separator.